# ReactNative: Can't press event parent component of Animated.View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been following along with a tutorial from DesignCode and the author wrapped the `AnimatedContainer` (a createAnimatedComponent) that has a `TouchableWithoutFeedBack` with an `onPress` event. In his recording he was able to press the card and it enlarged, however I cannot seem to invoke the onPress behavior even if I just put a console.log callback in there.

Am I missing something here? I've reviewed my code against his and its the same as far as I can tell. Is onPress behavior no longer supported?

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.openCard}>
        <AnimatedContainer
          style={{ width: this.state.cardWidth, height: this.state.cardHeight }}
        >
          <Cover>
            <Image source={this.props.image} />
            <AnimatedTitle style={{ top: this.state.titleTop }}>
              {this.props.title}
            </AnimatedTitle>
            <Author>by {this.props.author}</Author>
          </Cover>
          <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
        </AnimatedContainer>
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Full component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  Animated,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar
} from "react-native";

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const tabBarHeight = 83;

class Project extends Component {
  state = {
    cardWidth: new Animated.Value(315),
    cardHeight: new Animated.Value(460),
    titleTop: new Animated.Value(20)
  };

  openCard = () => {
    console.log("hello?");
    Animated.spring(this.state.cardWidth, { toValue: screenWidth }).start();
    Animated.spring(this.state.cardHeight, {
      toValue: screenHeight - tabBarHeight
    }).start();
    Animated.spring(this.state.titleTop, { toValue: 40 });
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.openCard}>
        <AnimatedContainer
          style={{ width: this.state.cardWidth, height: this.state.cardHeight }}
        >
          <Cover>
            <Image source={this.props.image} />
            <AnimatedTitle style={{ top: this.state.titleTop }}>
              {this.props.title}
            </AnimatedTitle>
            <Author>by {this.props.author}</Author>
          </Cover>
          <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
        </AnimatedContainer>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

export default Project;
```

Comment: You need to bind method in constructor or use "onPress={()=>this.openCard()}"

Comment: No dice, the function still wasnt being called.

Comment: Can you change openCard function to like this: openCard(){...}

Comment: Hm, I've been messing around with the app some more and cards are being enlarged but its wrong and out of order. If I swipe my cards they all behave like normal. However, if I click a single card, nothing will happen until i swipe a few cards and then another card will be enlarged. The error must be elsewhere. though, I have no idea where that error is yet..